# Google Sign in not working on release appbundle but working on release APK[Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter

I created a flutter release apk using the following command:

```
flutter build apk
```

and Google sign in worked perfectly on the release apk.

However, when I created a release appbundle using the following command:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Google sign in does not work.

Does Appbundle need a special configuration for the release key to work or what.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the android studio to build  signed app bundle.

just open your flutter project in android studio now open the android folder as your project directory.\and start building your app bundle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase Add your SHA-1 and SHA-256 and also add the google play console SHA-1 and SHA-256 to Firebase